# How to use field value as key name in Mongodb result

Tags: mongodb, field, key-value

Can somebody tell me please if is possible to use field value as key in mongodb result. If I have documents like

```
{'code': 'xxx', 'item': 'yyy'}
{'code': 'ooo', 'item': 'eee'}
```

I would like to get result where code value will be the key like

```
{'xxx': 'yyy'}, {'ooo': 'eee'}
```

Answer (score 17):

You have to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) if you want to build your keys dynamically. It takes an array of `k` and `v` fields as a parameter. To make it root you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) stage, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: [ [ { k: "$code", v: "$item" } ] ]}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: can be done with single stage https://mongoplayground.net/p/iHvydpjWMtU

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet that's right, thanks, modified my answer

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use it but its interesting to now it.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think thats possible. Mongo leaves the interpretation of the result to the application. Thats why mongodb is a shema-less database.