# How to create a custom object as output with field name as key in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Changing the output of an aggregation query where the key is the field name from the database.

I tried the following: 
[How to use field value as key name in Mongodb result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438528/how-to-use-field-value-as-key-name-in-mongodb-result)

But it results in the following error:

> MongoError: $arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1

```
var data = await Message.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$message',
        last_message: { $last: '$date_create', },
        conversation: {
          $push: '$$ROOT',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        input: { $arrayElemAt: ['$conversation.message', 0] },
        output: { $arrayElemAt: ['$conversation.mainTopic', 0] },
        _id: 0,
      },
    },
    { $sort: { last_message: -1 } },
  ]);
```

I want to change the ouput from (current result):

> {
>      "input": "Test",
>      "output": "general"
>    },

TO:

> {
>      "input": "Test",
>      "output": { general: 1, },
>    },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `{ "input": "Test", "output": "general" }` into `{ "input": "Test", "output": { general: 1 } }` you need [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator which takes either an array of objects with `k` and `v` fields or an array of 2-element arrays like below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            input: 1,
            output: {
                $arrayToObject: [
                    [
                        [ "$output", 1 ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T-oe99uHHxa)

Comment: I already tried this (see my post) the error I get is:
MongoError: $arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1

And now:
MongoError: $arrayToObject requires an array of key-value pairs, where the key must be of type string. Found key type: null

Comment: without the $ I get the desired output but without the field value as it results in an error. It seems like it's not possible to use $ inside arrayToObject. Also your MongoDB playground has no result?

Comment: So I suppose that `$output` evaluates to `null` for some reason. Either you have some missing parts in your data or your path is defined incorrectly. Could you modify your answer and paste what you're exactly trying to transform ? Or if you have multiple documents and some of that contain `null` values you can use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/ to specify default value

Comment: @cxzzy you need dollar sign to refer to existing field, otherwise it's just a string, and it is allowed in $arrayToObject as you can see in Mongo playground example

Comment: Ah, that's it! Great! Thanks. I indeed had some empty values and setting a default value fixed the problem.