# $group result as the key value pair mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the pipeline stage before the `$group` stage computed the document like bellow

```
cycle_id | entity1 | entity 2
   1     |    0    |    1
   1     |    1    |    5
   2     |    0    |    3
```

I am able to group them using bellow script

```
{ 
        "$group" : { 
            "_id" : "$cycle_id", 
            "entity1" : { 
                "$sum" : "$entity1"
            }, 
            "entity2" : { 
                "$sum" : "$entity3"
            }, 
            "entity3" : { 
                "$sum" : "$entity3"
            }
        }
    }
```

This generated output like bellow:

```
cycle_id | entity1 | entity 2
   1     |    1    |    6
   2     |    0    |    3
```

but what I am looking for is something where I can project it like an array of key-value pair

```
{
 1:{
  entity1: 1,
  entiry2: 6
 },
 2:{
  entity1: 3,
  entiry2: 4
 }
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve the above result. I tried to look around [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) but wasn't quite successful with that yet.

Thanks,
Nixit

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438528/how-to-use-field-value-as-key-name-in-mongodb-result/54444664#54444664 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use field value as key name in Mongodb result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438528/how-to-use-field-value-as-key-name-in-mongodb-result) Making it as dup, check this implemented :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/j_c0_RzfCoU

Comment: no this is not a dup as it is returning the array of dictionaries and not one single dict.

Comment: You mentioned "an array of key-value" pair, isn't that array of dictionaries? Aggregation always return an array, if you want an array of a single dictionary, you can use @whoami implementation, and using $group with $mergeObjects

Comment: apologies for the confusion updated my question for the desired result. above answers will created the array of dict instead of one single dict will all the keys in one dict.

Comment: @NixitPatel : Please provide proper data, keys can't stand on their own in an array I think you've missed to wrap `1` & `2` in an object like this :: `[
 { 1:{
  entity1: 1,
  entiry2: 6
 },
 2:{
  entity1: 3,
  entiry2: 4
 }}
]` better edit this question with proper desired o/p for future reference..

Comment: @whoami I have updated the output it should be curly braces instead of square

Comment: @NixitPatel: With any read pipeline, no matter what aggregation will always return an array either `empty array` or `array with one object` or `array with multiple objects` !! You need to get the first element of the response array in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Group without any condition and merge all documents (Converted objects) into an object */
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "",
        data: {
          $mergeObjects: {
            $arrayToObject: [ [ { k: { $toString: "$_id" }, v: { "entity1": "$entity1", "entity2": "$entity2" } } ] ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    /** Replace `data` field as a root of the document */
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2-P5WpYBzs7)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)